# How to delete duplicated rows and update the table

Tags: mysql

I have duplicated rows in tables.

I have two table which are connected by a foreign key

```
regions (id)
orders (region_id)
```

The regions have duplicated names. I want to delete these duplicated rows and update orders table that duplicated foreign key will now be set to only left existing name in regions table.

Example:

```
regions table:

id  name
1 | test
2 | test
3 | foo

orders table:

id region_id
6 | 1
7 | 2
9 | 3
```

I want

```
orders table:

id region_id
6 | 1
7 | 1
9 | 3

regions table:

id  name
1 | test
3 | foo
```

I can get duplicated rows with this SQL:

```
SELECT name, count(id) as cnt FROM regions 
GROUP BY name HAVING cnt > 1
```

How can I connect this select with order table and delete duplicated rows and update the table?

Comment: What's the logic for which record to save of the duplicates? I assume the first (i.e. lowest primary key). Do you have access to another technology. It's probably harder to do this with MySQL directly.

Comment: Lukas it is not just delete rows. I need to update foreign keys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the orders table, something like:

```
update  orders
join    regions r1
on      r1.id = orders.region_id
set     orders.region_id = 
        (
        select  min(r2.id)
        from    regions r2
        where   r2.name = r1.name
        )
```

After that, you can delete duplicate rows with:

```
delete  regions
from    regions
where   id not in
        (
        select  id
        from    (
                select  min(id) as id
                from    regions
                group by
                    name
                ) as SubqueryAlias
        )
```

The double subquery is required to avoid the MySQL error `ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 36: You can't specify target table 'regions' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: thx for help. I din't know that you need souble subquery for this.